# Gas valve key handle

Tags: gas

I am new to relying on gas in a house. We just recently moved into this home over a month ago and noticed there was a gas valve with a key handle, recently we had a gas leak from a company not making sure the dryer we had gotten installed was correct. It happened a few hours ago. Then I noticed the key to the valve fell off or was moved. Now I am wondering what are these symbols, and if the fireplace is off or on? And is the key
Supposed to be connected, or tightened to the wall or loose?

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, the symbols are just brand markings, and have no inherent meaning beyond that.

Comment: "I am new to relying on gas in a house." - Okay, so maybe let's not use that at least until you're comfortable with the stove, and hide the key somewhere. - If you turn that on w/o being ready to light it and knowing how to, it's going to be a bad day. Have a friend come over and show you. If you're asking what that is, then *you* don't mess with it.

Answer (score 8):

The valve key is usually a removable handle. This is for safety- so the gas does not get turned on without intention.

I cannot tell from your photo but most gas valves have similar keys- see the generic picture below taken from the web.

[image: Generic rendered image of two gas keys, in silver or chrome] 
<sub>from https://www.amazon.ca/Pieces-Fireplace-Universal-Outdoor-Fireplaces/dp/B0BQYG26BT</sub>

Comment: You need to provide a link to show where the image came from. Just saying it was found on the web does not meet the Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Would a radiator bleed key fit correctly?

Comment: @MichaelKaras How's that for a source attribution?  Not sure if it's exactly where kyle found it, but is the same image and the top of the search results.

Comment: @Criggie - That works OK